# How to plot colors based on cell values on a timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a data which contains 16 columns, from which 1 column is "Time" column and other 15 columns are columns that represent colors. Data looks like this:

[image: Color columns]
[image: Time column]

What I need is to have a plot in which at every timestamp represent these 15 colors.

The output should look like this:

[image: Output]

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try something on your own yet?

Comment: Hi @user2246849, I´ve tried to do it with matplotlib bar plot, take time as an "x" value and length of the dataframe as an "y" value, then added the color from "SG15", but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `bar`, it's usually more convenient in these cases to use the normal `plot` in segments. Here is a toy example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':[0.3, 1.5, 1.8, 4.7, 5.8],
                   'SG1':['red', 'green', 'grey', 'yellow', 'red'], 
                   'SG2':['grey', 'red', 'grey', 'yellow', 'grey'], 
                   'SG3':['red', 'red', 'grey', 'yellow', 'red'],
                   'SG4':['red', 'green', 'grey', 'green', 'red']})
```

```
   Time     SG1     SG2     SG3    SG4
0     1     red    grey     red    red
1     2   green    grey     red  green
2     3    grey    grey    grey  green
3     4  yellow  yellow  yellow  green
4     5     red    grey     red    red
```

The code:

```
LINE_THICKNESS = 10 
FIG_SIZE = (4, 3) # Size (width, height).

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=FIG_SIZE)

groups = sorted([c for c in df.columns if 'SG' in c])
for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    colors = df[group]
    
    for (color, t0), t1 in zip(zip(colors, df['Time']), df['Time'][1:]):
        ax.plot([t0, t1], [i, i], color=color, linewidth=LINE_THICKNESS)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylim([-0.5, len(groups)-0.5])
plt.yticks(range(len(groups)), groups)
plt.ylabel('Groups')
plt.title("Signal plan 2", weight='bold')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image: plot example]

You can play with `LINE_THICKNESS` and `FIG_SIZE` for the dimensions.

**EDIT:**

The [`zip` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) takes iterables and aggregates them in a tuple. So:

- `zip(colors, df['Time'])` gets the (color, time_start) tuple, to associate the timepoints with the color. Let's call this `time_colors` in the next line.
- `zip(time_colors, df['Time'][1:])` similarly associates the (color, time_start) tuples with the next timepoint. This is needed to know the limit to stop drawing the line.

Comment: Thank you, this one works!! I just have one question though - what does the "zip(zip(colors, df['Time']), df['Time'][1:])" in the second for loop mean?

Comment: @Jan Zarcký I edited the answer with a short explanation. I suggest you to learn to use `zip`, it's really useful!